# Hibernate create domain instance with foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reflection

i have domain classes like this:

extremely Simplified:

```
class Person extends Domain {
  Set<Contracts> contracts;

  //...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Contracts> getContracts() {
    return contracts;
  }
  //...
}

class Contract extends Domain {
  Person person;

  //...
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON__ID", nullable = false)
  public Person getPerson() {
    return this.person;
  }
  //...
}
```

I got a instance of a person and want to create a new contract. 
All over reflection.

My first try was something like that:

```
Domain domain = ...;
Method getter = resolveGetter(domain); // Person.getContracts()
ParameterizedType returnType = (ParameterizedType) getter.getGenericReturnType();

Class<Domain> cls = (Class<Domain>)returnType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
Domain instance = cls.newInstance();

OneToMany annotation = getter.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class);
String mappedBy = annotation.mappedBy();
```

and now i need the setter method from the cls wich the mappedBy descripe to set the person in the contract.
But how i get the setter correctly?

A possible solution is via method name of the class but i think its ugly. And i dont find a method of the hibernate framework to do this.

Has someone an idea?

Usage:

- Java 6 hibernate-core-3.6.10
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1

-- Update:

I got the hibernate property via

```
JavaReflectionManager manager = new JavaReflectionManager();
XClass xClass = manager.toXClass(cls);

List<XProperty> declaredProperties = xClass.getDeclaredProperties(XClass.ACCESS_PROPERTY); // Our domains use only Property Access
for (XProperty xProperty : declaredProperties) {
  if(xProperty.getName().equals(mappedBy)) {
     // How to set the value in the property?
  }
}
```

Now were the question how to set the value in the property?

Comment: Why use reflection? If you use reflection, then of course you'll have to get methods by name to be able to call them. That's basically the principle of reflection.

Comment: I don't think that doing this with reflection is that easy. Hibernate often returns proxy objects, especially for collections, so that it can implement lazy loading and other such optimisations. Reflection gets really hard in these circumstances.

Comment: But hibernate have to get the setter for the mappedBy annotation too. And i dont think that they go directy with the getter name.
Why Reflection? would i dont use reflection i would have to write admin masks for about 60 domain objects.